# why is my arima model giving NaNs in predictions?

Tags: time-series, predict, arima, sarimax

I'm trying to predict weekly sales of a store from the famous walmart dataset - a simple time series prediction exercise. I fit the model and run predict command, but the predictions are all NaNs.

The data is stationary.
I've taken rolling mean over 10 weeks, detrended the sales numbers using this rolling mean, differenced the data.

Auto arima detects a ARIMA (1,0,2) model.
I fit the model and predict, but the predictions are all NaNs. Also, the predicted NaNs start with index of almost 10 years ago! Same happens for A sarimax model.

Please help me solve this issue!
Attaching my code below:

```
train = rmdetdiff.iloc[:110]['weekly_sales']
test = rmdetdiff.iloc[110:]['weekly_sales']

model1 = ARIMA(train, order=(1,0,2))
model1_fit = model1.fit()

start = len(train)
end = len(train)+len(test)-1

rmdetdiff['arima_pred'] = model1_fit.predict(start=start, end=end, dynamic=True)
rmdetdiff[['arima_pred','weekly_sales']].plot(legend=True)
```

Here is the plot after predictions: (all the blank space before the weekly_sales is created after the model1.fit command.)
[image: plot after prediction]
shape of rmdetdiff is (133,1)

Comment: are u using  statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA?  i don't think predict function supports start and end as an arguments.

Comment: no I am using statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.... using older version simply throws up an error of command not implemented, so it is directly ruled out. But thanks for your comment!

Comment: I don't know that version if that supports but you can use a for loop of your desired length and predict only 1 item per loop. that won't give you this nan vaues i think.